# Stanford NLP annotate text is very slow

Tags: java, performance, stanford-nlp

I am working on a NLP project in Java running on a Windows machine using the Stanford CoreNLP. I want to annotate a large text article from this. The code that I have written is as follow;

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref, regexner");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline =   new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
Annotation document = new Annotation("Text to be annotated. This text is very long!");
pipeline.annotate(document); // this line takes a long time
```

The annotation of the text take up quite a long time. 
Roughly for about a 60 words this particular line takes about 16 seconds which is way too long.

Is there a way to speed up this processing or is there anything that I have missed.
Pls tell me what I can do.
Thanx in advance :-)

**EDIT**

Code sample

```
    public TextReader() {
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, regexner");
pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
extractor = CoreMapExpressionExtractor.
                            createExtractorFromFiles(TokenSequencePattern.getNewEnv(), "Stanford NLP\\stanford-corenlp-full-2015-01-29\\stanford-corenlp-full-2015-01-30\\tokensregex\\color.rules.txt");
text = "Barak Obama was born on August 4, 1961,at Kapiolani Maternity & Gynecological Hospital "
+ " in Honolulu, Hawaii, and would become the first President to have been born in Hawaii. His mother, Stanley Ann Dunham,"
+ " was born in Wichita, Kansas, and was of mostly English ancestry. His father, Barack Obama, Sr., was a Luo from Nyang’oma"
+ " Kogelo, Kenya. He studied at the University of Westminster. His favourite colour is red.";
Logger.getLogger(TextReader.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Annotator starting...", text); // LOG 1
Annotation document = new Annotation(text);
pipeline.annotate(document);
Logger.getLogger(TextReader.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Annotator finished...", props); // LOG 2
sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);
for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
   //the tokens of the sentence are taken and iterated over
   // the NER, POS and lemma of the tokens are stores iteratively
}
}
```

I realized the time between LOG 1 and LOG 2 is about 16 seconds. What i need is to process much longer text and this takes a very long time. Please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanx =D

Comment: Well, you're using a bunch of annotators, and some do real work (e.g., `ner`). I'd start by removing those that are "likely" to take up time and see (a) where your performance issues are, and (b) if you need what they're providing. As soon as you start classifying what each word things get tricky.

Comment: I would guess that 95% of that 16 seconds was spent loading data and initializing internal data structures.  As Dave mentioned, try removing annotators that you don't need.  I believe that newer versions of the library are thread safe so you could initialize the pipeline once (perhaps at startup) and reuse it rather than create a new instance for each document that needs to be annotated.

Comment: thanx for your comments, but the iniitalization of the pipeline (i.e. where I put the annotators and create the pipeline object) is not included in the 16 secs. I need to run the last line multiple times so I have the rest of the code running only once. Still the last line which runs for different text segments alone takes 16 secs.

Comment: So is there anything i can to do make the running time of the line `pipeline.annotate(document);` faster?

Comment: I just read this from their website "Processing a short text like this is very inefficient. It takes a minute to load everything before processing begins. You should batch your processing." Looks like it is slow

Comment: my text is not small. what i need to do is to annotate an entire text from a Wikipedia article for further processing. The annotation takes time, thus the entire process takes a really long time. If there is a way to break up the text segment and run in different threads or something similar , pls tell me how I can go about it? :-(

Answer (score 3):

Is the text a single long sentence? The runtime of the parser is O(n^3) with respect to the length of the sentence, which gets quite slow on sentences longer than ~40 words. If you remove the "parse, dcoref, regexner" annotators, does it speed up? And, does it then slow down again if you re-add "parse"?

If what you care about is dependency parses rather than constituency parses, the new "depparse" annotator will produce these much faster; though, our coref does not work with dependency parses yet (coming soon!).

Comment: I cannot remove the parse and the regexner annotators as I need to get the dependency tree and I have written some NER rules that is used by regexner. </br> I am using bothe the dependency  and constituency parses that I can get via 'parse'. As per the documentation, 'depparse' only provides dependency  parsing.

Comment: The text is not a single sentence. The text is something like that text found in a Wikipedia article. Standards sentence lengths, mostly not above 40 words per line.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of a program that takes too long? 60 words of text, if not a single sentence, should not take that long...

Comment: I have added a sample code as an edit to the question. Thanx :)

Comment: Replacing "parse" with "depparse" reduced runtime by ~10 seconds for me. I'm using the quote annotator.